# How does PCIe endpoint remembers its Bus Device Function Number?

Tags: pci, pci-e

How does the PCIe endpoint claim the configuration transaction since there is no register (in Type0 config space) defined by PCIe specification which holds the Bus Device and Function number.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming. its a hardware implementation quesiton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device must capture the destination address from the first config transaction it receives and store it for use in outgoing transactions. Since PCIe is actually point-to-point, not a bus, a device only receives config transactions that are intended for it.